# TCPDF - Codeigniter - Get data in the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I really hope that someone can help me!

I'm trying to create a pdf file with some data that I get from a query, the pdf creator is in the controller.

Here is my model:

```
function assistiti()
{
    $user =  $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    $userId = $user->id;
    $query = $this->db->get_where('assistiti', array('assistito_da' => $userId));
    return $query->result();
}
```

That I call from the controller:

```
$data['assistiti'] = $this->assistiti_m->assistiti();
```

In the same controller I create the pdf file with a foreach loop through data:

```
foreach($data as $post){

    $nome = $post->nome;
    $cognome =  $post->cognome;
    $tribunale = $post->tribunale;

    $tbl .= '<tr><td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">'.$nome.'</td>'; 
    $tbl .= '<td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">'.$cognome.'</td>';
    $tbl .= '<td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">'.$tribunale.'</td>    </tr>';

;}

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header.$tbl.$tbl_footer , true, false, false, false, '');
```

and obviously it does't work...it returns to me a classic `Trying to get property of non-object` and the only way that I found to return some data is putting the array index like that:

```
$nome = $post[0]nome;
$cognome =  $post[0]->cognome;
$tribunale = $post[0]->tribunale;
```

but obviously it returns me only the first row.

Here is a print_r of `$data`:

```
Array ( [assistiti] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id_assistiti] => 1 [nome] =>     Matte [cognome] => Dama [luogo_nascita] => Milano [data_nascita] => 1986-10-01 [residenza]   => Milano [dimora] => Milano [telefono] => 545431453143 [tribunale] => Milano) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id_assistiti] => 2 [nome] => dario [cognome] => vozzi [luogo_nascita] => 0 [data_nascita] => 0000-00-00 [residenza] => pesaro [dimora] => [telefono] => [tribunale] => ancona ) ) )
```

How can I get all the entries???

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `Array of stdClass Objects`. You can access them as:

```
foreach($data as $post)
{
    foreach($post as $p)
    {
        $tbl .= '<tr><td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">'.$p->nome.'</td>'; 
        $tbl .= '<td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">'.$p->cognome.'</td>';
        $tbl .= '<td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">'.$p->tribunale.'</td>    </tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Raidenace can you check my forum? I also have a problem regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917689/how-do-i-display-data-in-my-foreach-in-eod-tcpdf?noredirect=1#comment71016878_41917689

Answer (score 0):

You are saving your model query results in a specific key(assistiti) inside the array $data, and then you are fetching the whole array in the foreach loop. This way, you got to loop through the specific array, inside the array $data:

```
foreach($data['assistiti'] as $post){

    $nome = $post->nome;
    $cognome =  $post->cognome;
    $tribunale = $post->tribunale;

    $tbl .= '<tr><td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">'.$nome.'</td>'; 
    $tbl .= '<td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">'.$cognome.'</td>';
    $tbl .= '<td style="border:1px solid #000;text-align:center">'.$tribunale.'</td>    </tr>';

;}

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header.$tbl.$tbl_footer , true, false, false, false, '');
```

Comment: @Arthur sir, can you check my forum? i also have a problem like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917689/how-do-i-display-data-in-my-foreach-in-eod-tcpdf?noredirect=1#comment71016878_41917689