# How do I display data in my foreach in EOD tcpdf?

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I am new in the tcpdf.. I am currently doing a project where I am using the tcpdf(because I want to export my table in pdf that has a template of it). I tried to do some research and I've found the method writeHTML(). In this method I can now make any html tags

**Controller**

```
public function testing(){
        $this->load->library('Pdf');
        $this->load->model('newModel');
        $data['accounts'] = $this->newModel->get('users');
        $this->load->view('admin/testing',$data);
    }
```

**View**

```
$txt = <<<EOD
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <tr>

        <td>COL 2 - ROW 1</td>
        <td>COL 3 - ROW 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($accounts as $try):?>
        <td>$try->first_name</td>
        <td>Hala2   </td>
        <?php endforeach?>
    </tr>


</table>
EOD;
$pdf->writeHTML($txt, true, false, false, false, '');
```

**Model**

```
public function get($table)
    {
        $result = $this->db->get($table);
        return $result->result();
    }
```

Question: How can I display all my data in EOD? Is there any method like writePHP()? To allow me to do some php coding?

Comment: what is your model's code and where you want to display data?

Comment: In my model it is just $this->db->get($table);

Comment: in which formar results are fetched.

Comment: Check again my forum, i already put my model

Comment: you want to display your result inside table of `EOD`.Am i right?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use loop directly inside `here document(<<<)`.You have to concatenate.Like this

```
  <?php
$accounts = array('name'=>'angle');//assumed array
//print_r($accounts);
$txt = <<<EOD
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <tr>

        <td>COL 2 - ROW 1</td>
        <td>COL 3 - ROW 1</td>
    </tr>
EOD;
foreach($accounts as $key=>$value){
$txt.=<<<EOD
    <tr>
      <td>{$accounts['name']}</td>
      <td>It is easy</td>
    </tr>
EOD;
 }
$txt.=<<<EOD

</table>
EOD;

echo $txt;
?>
```

In your model retrun result in array format.So that you can try like above

```
public function get($table)
    {
        $result = $this->db->get($table);
        return $result->result_array();//it returns result in array format
    }
```

Comment: I also tried that and it still not working sir.. i display nothing

Comment: try edited answer.But i don;t think that you can loop inside here document.

Comment: So, where should I put my loop?

Comment: you can concatenate.

Comment: @Angel try like above hope it will woks greatly.

Comment: There's some error "TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file"

Comment: I think this error is related to  your library.So i have not idea on TCPDF.You can make next question.But your problem in this question is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

use mpdf insted tcpdf if you are looking for getting data from database and put into html and create pdf.

[mpdf docs and library](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)